# Extract a portion of a string using excel formula

Tags: excel-formula

I need to extract the central number in the string below using an excel formula

```
Min { {r4} , {r7} , {r10}}<={r3}<= Max {{r4} , {r7} , {r10}}
```

here it would be 3. The string is dynamic e.g:

```
Min { {r4011} , {r4012}}<={r4010}<= Max {{r4011} , {r4012}}
```

Needs to be catered for also (here i need `4010`)

Comment: I'm trying combinations of FIND, LEN, RIGHT, but just not getting it so far.

Comment: Formatted Formulas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work

=MID(D1755,FIND("<=",D1755,1)+4,FIND("}<= Max",D1755,1) - (FIND("<=",D1755,1)+4))